# Print terminal output on the text cursor position

Tags: python

Just a question out of curiosity, is it possible to print terminal output at a text cursor position.
Say for example. If I print 'Hello World' in terminal, and currently my text cursor is in notepad, is there a way, on how can I get the output copied to the current positioned text cursor in real time without saving the file. Any suggestions/ help would be appreciated. If possible can we achieve this using python.
Thanks.

Comment: Do some research. A module I would suggest that can take control of the terminal would be `curses`. Read about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Comment: The editor you're using would need to expose some kind of interface to get that information. I don't believe "current position of cursor" is something that most editors expose, unless they're expecting plug-in compatibility.

Comment: @TheMaker - Ouch! You really burned that guy! `curses` won't help with injecting keyboard events into the window of other processes.

Comment: It is possible to inject keyboard and mouse events into other windows via the windows api, but I don't have specifics. There are automated test programs that do that. You'll have the most luck looking at Windows api examples likely in C# or VB and then figuring out how to do the same thing through pythons win32api.

Comment: @tdelaney What do you mean by, _You really burned that guy!_?

Comment: @TheMaker - just annoyed by your comment, "do some research".

Answer (score 2):

With `pyautogui` you can write text with

```py
# type with quarter-second pause in between each key
pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)
```

This example has been taken from the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

## Edit

With this method, you would have to manually click on the input field in which you would like the text to be written.